# Page of connection in PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I just finished coding my login page, and I have these problems showing up, do you have any idea?

> [Tue Mar  9 22:55:11 2021] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: rounds in /home/swan/Epitech/Tweet_academie/html/connexion.php on line 28
> [Tue Mar  9 22:55:11 2021] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: sfopdgijtsposrigjsotij in /home/swan/Epitech/Tweet_academie/html/connexion.php on line 28

> [Tue Mar  9 22:55:11 2021] PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '='swan.marin@gmail.com' AND password='$65I6KH/.1F1w'' at line 1 in /home/swan/Epitech/Tweet_academie/db/connexiondb.php on line 37
> [Tue Mar  9 22:55:11 2021] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home/swan/Epitech/Tweet_academie/html/connexion.php on line 32

```
<html>

<?php
session_start();
include('../db/connexiondb.php'); // Fichier PHP contenant la connexion à votre BDD
 
// S'il y a une session alors on ne retourne plus sur cette page  
if (isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
header('Location: index.php');
    exit;
}

// Si la variable "$_Post" contient des informations alors on les traitres
if(!empty($_POST))
{
extract($_POST);
$valid = true;
 
    if (isset($_POST['connexion']))
    {
        $email = htmlentities(strtolower(trim($email)));
        $mdp = trim($mdp);

        // On fait une requête pour savoir si le couple mail / mot de passe existe bien
        $req = $DB->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? AND password=?", 
        array($email, crypt($mdp, "$6$rounds=5000$sfopdgijtsposrigjsotij$")));
        $req = $req->fetch();

        // Si on a pas de résultat alors c'est qu'il n'y a pas d'utilisateur correspondant au couple mail / mot de passe
        if ($req['id'] == "")
        {
            $valid = false;
            $er_email = "Le mail ou le mot de passe est incorrecte";
        }

 
        // S'il y a un résultat alors on va charger la SESSION de l'utilisateur en utilisateur les variables $_SESSION

        if ($valid)
        {
            $_SESSION['id'] = $req['id'];
            $_SESSION['name'] = $req['name'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $req['email'];
 
            header('Location:  index.php');
            exit;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Try changing the doble quotes to single ones on `array($email, crypt($mdp, "$6$rounds=5000$sfopdgijtsposrigjsotij$")));` - The double quotes allows php to seach for variables ($round, $sfopd... founded), single quotes just print the `$` like `string` ([Check this](https://dev.to/morinoko/double-quotes-vs-single-quotes-in-php-2e5n))

Comment: Sidenote: `extract($_POST);` -- don't do that. Someone could easily send a request that includes `$_POST['DB']` and voila: your database connection is gone. You should read the expected values from `$_POST['email'] and `$_POST['mdp']` instead of turning them and whatever else the user submitted into variables using `extract()`.

Comment: Just in case the password in the errormessage is a real one --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question

Comment: ok thanks, but my problem is still not solved

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Answer (score -2):

Line 28, check if you're receiving any value.

```
print_r($req);
```

it's probably an error in the sql command.

Comment: PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ? )

Comment: indeed, I think I have an error in my sql request but I do not see where it is